# Should I take a conference or tourist Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, tourist-visas, conferences

I am travelling to France for 6 days for a conference. After that, I want to  sightsee in Switzerland for 4 days. Do I apply for a Schengen visa for France or for Switzerland? Should I apply for the conference visa or tourist visa?

Comment: Is the conference the most important or the sightseeing? And if as important, where will you spend the most time?

Comment: Why are you in doubt? Have you checked the relevant pages from the local French or Swiss consulate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few rules that might appear to contradict each other in some cases but this one is pretty straightforward. France is the main destination, both in terms of length of stay and motivation for the trip (a conference typically trumps sightseeing, that what makes you travel to the Schengen area at this particular time). It doesn't really matter legally but it's also the first country you will enter. You need to apply with the French consulate in your place of residence.

For completeness, note that there is no such thing as a conference visa or a tourist visa. What you get in all cases is a Schengen visa, which covers both of these purposes (and many more). Simply check both boxes on the application form.

Comment: Thanks. One more doubt. My parents are also going with me for sightseeing, but they don't have to attend the conference, should they take visa to France or Switzerland?

Comment: @ShiS They are also staying in France for six days?

Comment: Yes, they are also staying for 6 days

Comment: Then, they should apply at the French consulate.